# Euler Tour of a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I wondering How we can calculate the Euler Tour of a tree ?
Should I use DFS for making a Euler Tour array.
[Tree Figure](http://community.topcoder.com/i/education/lca/LCA_006.gif)
[Euler Tree Figure](http://community.topcoder.com/i/education/lca/LCA_007.gif)

Comment: Your question is not about programming, thus it is off-topic. Please re-ask on a stackexchange site about theoretical computer science. And you should tell us, what you have tried and why it does not work. Nobody will do your homework for you.

Comment: The question might be on-topic if the goal is an actual implementation in code.

Comment: An Euler Tour for a tree cannot be calculated, as trees are cycle-free by definition. Or do you mean something similar to the follwoing link? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique

Comment: bfs is also going to work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find it using dfs. Here is a pseudo code.

```
tour = an empty list

def dfs(v):
    tour.push_back(v)
    for child in v.children():
        dfs(child)
        tour.push_back(v)

dfs(root)
```